# SQL JOIN - Elaborar conforme a base

Tags: sql

Gostaria de elaborar um SQL usando o LEFT JOIN.
Elaborei este SQL, mas não deu certo:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    p.parametro AS cidade, 
    cpr.codTipo AS tipoAcompanhante 
FROM 
    cadastroperfil AS cp, 
    cadastroprofissional AS cpr, 
    parametro AS p 
WHERE 
    cp.verificado = '1' 
        AND 
    cp.codCadastroPerfil = '11'
        AND 
    cpr.codCadastroPerfil = '11'
        AND 
    cp.codCidade = p.idParametro
```

O retorno é zero, mas tem registros no banco de dados.
Alguém consegue me sugerir alguma coisa? Grato

Todas estas tabelas tem relação uma com a outra, através do codCadastroPerfil

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: não são qual engine de banco de dados você está utilizando, mas você não teria que especificar que deseja um LEFT JOIN? Exemplo: FROM cadastroperfil as cp LEFT JOIN cadastroprofissional as cpr on (cp.codCadastroPerfil = cpr.codCadastroPerfil)?

Comment: Talvez sim mas como são varias tabelas acho que poderia ser num SQL so

Comment: a 1a frase do meu comentário ficou sem sentido. Eu perguntei qual engine de banco de dados vc está utilizando. De qualque maneira, postei um resposta. Espero que te ajude.

Comment: Olá, André. Você poderia ser mais específico sobre quais resultados gostaria de retornar? Seu SELECT não deixou muito claro qual a intenção da consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Baseado na pergunta e comentário, creio que a dúvida é em utilizar INNER JOIN com LEFT JOIN numa Query só.

Isso é possível e comum. Abaixo está um possível SQL baseado no modelo e que utiliza os dois tipos de Joins:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
CadastroPerfil CP
INNER JOIN CadastroProfissional CPS
ON (CP.CodCadastroPerfil = CPS.CodCadastroPerfil)
LEFT JOIN CadastroFotos CF
ON (CP.CodCadastroPerfil = CF.CodCadastroPerfil)
LEFT JOIN CadastroLocal CL
ON (CP.CodCadastroPerfil = CL.CodCadastroPerfil)
INNER JOIN CadastroPessoal CPE
ON (CP.CodCadastroPerfil = CPE.CodCadastroPerfil)
INNER JOIN Parametro P
ON (CP.CodCadastroPerfil = P.CodCadastroPerfil)
WHERE
cp.verificado = '1' 
AND cp.codCadastroPerfil = '11'
```

O SQL acima retornará registros da tabela CadastroPerfil CP mesmo que não haja correspondente (mesmo CodCadastroPerfil) nas tabelas CadastroFotos e CadastroLocal. Caso algum campo dessas duas tabelas seja colocado no SELECT, então os mesmo virão com valor NULL.